# Snake game using FPGA (ALTERA)

Tags: verilog, fpga

I am planning to make a snake game using the Altera DE2-115 and display it on LED Matrix
 Something similar to this in the video http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=niQmNYPiPw0
but still i don't know how to start,any help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's say you have a LED matrix like this:
[image: LED matrix schematic]

To answer not your question, but your comment about " if u can at least show me how to make the blinking LED i will be grateful :)", we can do as this:

```
module blink (input wire clk,  /* assuming a 50MHz clock in your trainer */
              output wire anode,  /* to be connected to RC7 */
              output wire cathode);  /* to be connected to RB7 */

  reg [24:0] freqdiv = 25'h0000000;
  always @(posedge clk)
    freqdiv <= freqdiv + 1;
  assign cathode = 1'b0;
  assign anode = freqdiv[24];
endmodule
```

This will make the top left LED to blink at a rate of 1,4 blinks per second aproximately.

This other example will show a running dot across the matrix, left to right, top to down:

```
module runningdot (input wire clk,  /* assuming a 50MHz clock in your trainer */
       output wire [7:0] anodes,  /* to be connected to RC0-7 */
       output wire [7:0] cathodes);  /* to be connected to RB0-7 */

  reg [23:0] freqdiv = 24'h0000000;
  always @(posedge clk)
    freqdiv <= freqdiv + 1;
  wire clkled = freqdiv[23];

  reg [7:0] r_anodes = 8'b10000000;
  reg [7:0] r_cathodes = 8'b01111111;
  assign anodes = r_anodes;
  assign cathodes = r_cathodes;

  always @(posedge clkled) begin
    r_anodes <= {r_anodes[0], r_anodes[7:1]};  /* shifts LED left to right */
    if (r_anodes == 8'b00000001)  /* when the last LED in a row is selected... */
      r_cathodes <= {r_cathodes[0], r_cathodes[7:1]}; /* ...go to the next row */
  end
endmodule
```

Your snake game, if using logic and not an embedded processor, is way much complicated than these examples, but it will use the same logic principles to drive the matrix.

Comment: that is great tanks alot , i just have one last problem, the physical connection of the Matrix with the altera , this is a photo of the matrix http://postimg.org/image/ynwceyp5h/

Comment: What is exactly your problem?

Comment: The matrix has 18 pins , 12 in one row and 6 on the other side , i am asking which pins will be connected to which pins in the ALTERA (i don't have a datasheet for the matrix)

Comment: Without the datasheet you will need to take a multimeter and probe the pins to check which led turns on.

Answer (score 2):

You'll have choose between 2 implementation routes:

1. Using a soft processor (NIOS II)
2. Writing the game logic in a hardware description language ([System]Verilog or VHDL)

The former will likely be the fastest route to achieving the completed game assuming you have some software background already, however if your intention is to learn to use FPGAs then option 2 may be more beneficial.  If you use a NIOS or other soft processor core you'll still need to create an FPGA image and interface to external peripherals.

To get started you'll want to look at some of the example designs that come with your board.  You also need to fully understand the underlying physical interface to the LED Matrix display to determine how to drive it.  You then want to start partitioning your design into sensible blocks - a block to drive the display, a block to handle user input, storage of state, the game logic itself etc.  Try and break them down sufficiently to decide what the interfaces to communicate between the blocks are going to look like.

In terms of implementation, for option 1 you will probably make use of Altera's SoC development environment called [Qsys](http://www.altera.co.uk/products/software/quartus-ii/subscription-edition/qsys/qts-qsys.html).  Again working from an existing example design as a starting point is probably the easiest way to get up-and-running quickly.  With option 2 you need to pick a hardware description language ([System]Verilog or VHDL or [MyHDL](http://www.myhdl.org/)) and code away in your favourite editor.

When you start writing RTL code you'll need a mechanism to simulate it.  I'd suggest writing block-level simulations for each of the blocks you write (ideally writing the tests based on your definitions of the interfaces before writing the RTL).  Assuming you're on a budget you don't have many options: Altera bundles a free version of Modelsim with their Quartus tool, there's the open source options of the [Icarus](http://iverilog.icarus.com/) simulator if using verilog or [GHDL](http://gna.org/projects/ghdl/) for VHDL.

When each block largely works run it through the synthesis tool to check FPGA resource utilisation and timing closure (the maximum frequency the design can be clocked at).  You probably don't care too much about the frequency implementing a game like snake but it's still good practice to be aware of how what you write translates into an FPGA implementation and the impact on timing.

You'll need to create a Quartus project to generate an FPGA bitfile - again working from an existing example design is the way to go.  This will provide pin locations and clock input frequencies etc.  You may need to write timing constraints to define the timing to your LED Matrix display depending on the interface.

Then all you have to do is figure out why it works in simulation but not on the FPGA ;)

Comment: Thanks for your reply,i will use verilog , i am wondering if u have any links for tutorials how to make the LED work with the ALTERA?
and will the snake game code be the same if it wasn't to be displayed on the LED,thanks

Comment: Based upon your questions ("how to make the LED work with the ALTERA"), I'd suggest to you to start with something more easy, like for example, a blinking LED, then a Knight Rider efect with multiple LED's, then displaying figures in the LED matrix, then maybe a marquee with the LED Matrix, and so on.

Comment: Thanks but i really have no idea how the LED matrix work with the ALTERA , if u can at least show me how to make the blinking LED i will be grateful :)

Comment: Provide more information about the LED matrix you are using, and how it is connected to your ALTERA device. Then ask another question about how to blink one LED using Verilog and ALTERA.

Comment: It is 8x8 LED Matrix , it will be connected by female-female wires.
you can see the pic of the Matrix at https://drive.google.com/?authuser=0&usp=gmail#my-drive